# The tag [libraries] should removed since [library] is blacklisted

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

[library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/library) [has been blacklisted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182243/its-time-to-blacklist-library), so why is [libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/libraries) still there?

The tag wiki is

> Use this tag for questions about software libraries. This tag is NOT for questions about computer programs used in public lending libraries or other brick-and-mortar libraries.

[library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/library) has been blacklisted and the same reasons apply to [libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/libraries), so we should also blacklist [libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/libraries).

There is also [lib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lib) tag that has no wiki.

Comment: `library` would be made a synonym of `libraries`, if it existed. Its absence is not a reason to condemn `libraries`. If `libraries` is useful as a tag is debatable, perhaps, but your reasoning is flawed.

Comment: @MartijnPieters what is the difference between [library] and [libraries] in the context of stackoverflow?

Comment: The same difference as between [`list` and `lists`](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/list/synonyms), or [`string` and `strings`](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/string/synonyms), or [`framework` and `frameworks`](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/frameworks/synonyms). Pluralisation.

Comment: A *proper* reason to want to remove `libraries` is to point out that [`library` has been blacklisted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182243/its-time-to-blacklist-library). That is **not clear** from your post.

Comment: @MartijnPieters ok I will edit it

Comment: Synonyms of blacklisted tags should be burned by default.

Comment: Now there is also [tag:lib] tag