# This is not the place to ad [lib]

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

I recently stumbled on the [lib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lib) tag, with no wiki and 589 questions covering a wide range of topics.

The commonality in all the questions is that users are referring to a "library", for which it is clearly a synonym/abbreviation.

Some are just mentioning the library they use. Some are (off-topic) requesting a library recommendation.  Many are talking about a [shared-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shared-library) or [static-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/static-library) or [class-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/class-library), all of which have their own tags.

However, the `library` tag has been blacklisted. I suspect many questions with this tag were by users attempting to use the `library` tag, finding none, and substituting this instead.

A [previous burnination request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260308/the-tag-libraries-should-removed-since-library-is-blacklisted) in 2014 suggested removing [libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/libraries); comments indicated we should blacklist a direct synonym.  The [lib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lib) tag was created in 2017, a few years after that discussion.

**1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

No.

The contents of the questions to which it is applied cover a wide range of topics, all of which use (or the user is requesting) a particular library, but are many different libraries (or the process of importing libraries, etc.).   In most cases, if a library-related tag is needed, [libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/libraries) should suffice.

**2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

The concepts [shared-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shared-library) or [static-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/static-library) or [class-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/class-library) which are on-topic have their own tags.  When dealing with multiple [libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/libraries) there's a tag for that.

This tag is an easy place to find close-able questions asking for library recommendations, though.  329 of the 589 questions are unanswered.

**3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

No.  The posts mentioned a library in the question.  The [lib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lib) tag adds nothing.  It's not useful for searching.  Only 83 of the 589 questions have more than one upvote denoting useful questions. [Sorting the tag by votes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lib?tab=Votes) shows a few useful questions at the top of the list, none of which need the [lib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lib) tag for their usefulness.

**4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

Yes, it means a library, which was [burninated in 2012 and blacklisted in 2013](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182243/its-time-to-blacklist-library).  Sadly <s>it appears a [single question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18870656/math-library-against-own-library-in-c-sharp) survived this purge and</s> [lib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lib) came roaring back to life in 2017.

**Is the tag harmful?**

In a large number of questions it's one of five tags, possibly replacing a better tag.  It's actively being (mis)used, with 6 questions tagged thus this week, 16 this month.  At 588 (surviving) questions since January 2017, that's an average of 10.5 per month.

Comment: Comparing some of the oldest "newest" and "active" questions, looks like the tag was created on [this question about iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41645320) (Jan 14 '17). The question you linked got the tag added on Jan 29 '21 instead.

Comment: [[frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/frameworks)] also has the same problem.

Comment: I think the [tag:lib] tag should be removed.  It is irksome that there are so many questions with the tag — it makes the effort of removing it that much harder.

Comment: Please, [lib]erate us from this awful tag!

Comment: Since it doesn't add useful information, a moderator could just delete the tag, no need to edit all those questions manually.

Comment: @CrisLuengo bad tags typically have a lot of bad questions too that either need to be cleaned up, or that should be closed and in many cases deleted.  Doing that is part of why the normal burnination process includes human review of all questions.  Mass tag removal is only for exceptional cases where human review in impractical due to the number of questions involved.  Even there questions with only the bad tag need addressed first.

Comment: @DanIsFiddlingByFirelight I understand burnination is good excuse to review some potentially bad questions, but you could also just sit there and look at random old questions and make decisions about them. I mean, reviewing the questions with this tag is not strictly necessary. I can think of better ways to waste time.

Comment: @CrisLuengo sadly, the tool to do that isn't exposed to moderators. Only staff.

Comment: Wait, there is a [tag:libraries] tag?

Comment: This tag is still around — there have been six questions in the last 7 days, all unanswered.  I came across it once more because of a new question.  I'm not sure what it takes to get this burnination request moving.  Do we simply have to do it manually?  WIth 63 upvotes and 6 downvotes on this question, it is clear that the majority of the people who've considered the issue agree it should be removed.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with the proposal — the [lib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lib) tag should be burninated.  Where it makes sense, questions should be retagged with one of the more specific library-type tags:

- [shared-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shared-library)
- [static-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/static-library)
- [class-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/class-library)